# c# Linq - Check for multiple in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of transactions and i need to find if there is more then 1 account

i did

```
   var MultipleAccounts = list.GroupBy(t => t.AccountId).Count() > 1;
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Does it need to be LINQ? You could have a `HashSet<int> accountIds` and then iterate over each account and call `ISet<T>.Add` which will return `false` the first time you see a duplicate.

Comment: i have it in a List already (for the next thing im doing), is it worth to cast to HashSet?

Comment: Are you trying to see if there is more than one group or if any of the groups have more than one member?

Comment: @ta.speot.is What's the benefit of keeping a hash set that should only contain a single item? Assuming `list` is non-empty, you could just have an `accountId = list[0].AccountId;`, and then compare each item's `AccountId` to that explicitly. (Oh wait -- you're commenting as if this question is about checking that all account IDs are unique, but I don't think that's what the question is about.)

Comment: I just want to know if i have more then 1 AccountId in my list, And maybe grouping is too much work for that check

Comment: @hvd love that look gr8 thanks!!

Comment: Define "better", what are you trying to achieve? Readability? Performance?other quality attributes? HashSet is not required here, and even if it was you would probably use a Dictionary instead.

Comment: "Better" i mean Performance, And @hvd's answer looks just what i was looking for.

Comment: Whether I'd actually suggest that approach depends on how you intend to use it though. It wouldn't surprise me too much if you already have the opportunity to check for multiple accounts earlier, and it wouldn't surprise me if a change in data structures might eliminate the need to check.

Comment: In order to determine what would perform better, it helps to know what your common problem sizes are and what operating environment is. You wouldn't use the same solution when you have small data sets coupled with a code path executed thousands of times per second as you would with a large set only executed once a day. In the former, you'd probably start to care more about GC behavior (which will hurt other parts of your code) on top of execution time. The latter you'd probably just care about overall execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to lose the single-line I prefer the use of `!.All(item => bool)` or `.Any(item => bool)` as I think it's the most semantic and easiest to read, as well as being a good candidate for the fastest.

```
var accountId = accounts[0].AccountId;
var hasMultipleAccounts = !accounts.All(account => account.AccountId == accountId);
```

Alternatively, and perhaps even more semantically, you could use `.Any(item => bool)` instead of `.All(item => bool)`.

```
var accountId = accounts[0].AccountId;
var hasMultipleAccounts = accounts.Any(account => account.AccountId != accountId);
```

Things to watch out for are making sure you have at least one item (so that accounts[0] doesn't fail) and not doing a multiple enumeration of your IEnumerable. You say you're working with a List, so multiple enumeration shouldn't cause you any trouble, but when you just have an unknown IEnumerable it's important to be careful.

Comment: will it return after finding the first mismatch? or continue running through the list?

Comment: he just wants all multiple accounts, not true/false if first account is repeated everywhere

Comment: This computes the wrong result. It sets `hasMultipleAccounts` to `true` when all of the accounts are the same.

Comment: @CMS This will return after finding the first mismatch. All Enumerates until the predicate returns false, then immediately returns false itself. Note that I've added some cases to watch out for.

Comment: i think you need a `!= `

Comment: @Enigmativity and @CMS, that's embarrassing, forgot the `!`. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: yup but the concept is short and quick!

Comment: @Sam - a `!` at the start may force a full evaluation. Using `.Any` with a `!=` would be more efficient.

Comment: @Sam Currect !!

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah I spotted the Any myself and added it already, but thanks. Not sure how the other forces a full evaluation though? I think they're functionally equivalent, but I have been awake for too long...

Comment: guys whats the madness today??/ why all this downvotes. lets give some upvotes, all answers are good (better then what was posted in the question)

Comment: @Sam - With `!accounts.All(account => account.AccountId == accountId);` if there are a million records all with the same `AccountId` then this will check all of them to make sure that they are the same. Thus forcing full evaluation. However, my brain had a small fart as the `Any`/`!=` combination will do exactly the same thing in this case. You're right - they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah, without somehow pre-processing the list that's always going to be the best worst-case.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```
var MultipleAccounts = list.Select(t => t.AccountId).Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
```

This should be exceedingly fast as it will stop iterating the source `list` as soon as it finds a second `AccountId`.

Anytime you execute a full `.Count()` it has to iterate the full source list.

---

You can test this with the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Data().Select(t => t).Distinct().Skip(1).Any());
}

private Random __random = new Random();

public IEnumerable<int> Data()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var @return = __random.Next(0, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(@return);
        yield return @return;
    }
}
```

A typical run looks like this:

```
7
9
True
```

Comment: i dont know if you know, but .Distinct() is making a new enumeration that may be slower than just using my method above.

Comment: @CMS - Your method still makes an enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is what i found the quickest

```
    public bool HasMultipleAccounts(List<Account> list)
    {
        foreach (var account in list)
            if (account.AccountId != list[0].AccountId)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

usage: `var MultipleAccounts = HasMultipleAccounts(list);`

Credits: @hvd

i know its more code but if you think what the cpu needs to do its the quickest

Comment: he wants to have a list of accounts, not comparing result wih first account

Comment: @MaksimSimkin - There's nothing about that in the question.